# elegant CSS positioning for spacing

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```html
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
    <div class="MyClass"></div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.MyClass {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

All these elements are going to be positioned on one line with a space in between of 5px. The problem is that there will also be a space of 5px at the end. I want to have Wrapper really wrap the `.MyClass` divs so that there's no space on the edge.

Now I can think of several ways of doing this:

- with jquery, set the right margin of the last element to 0.
- with CSS create a new class - `.MyClassForLastElement` with `marin-right` set to 0.
- creating a negative `right-margin` of -5px for `.Wrapper`.

I was wondering if there's an elegant and clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there is a perfect solution, I use to do that:

```css
.MyClass {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.MyClass:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I do it with with `first-child` since it is supported in IE6-7 while `last-child` is not.

Comment: I totally agree with you, even I would say "last-child" doesn't work neither in IE8. So, "first-child" would be better choice because work in IE8 and some versions of IE7, obviously, neither in the so hated IE6.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the last child to have a `margin-right` use the `last-child` psuedo-selector.

```css
.MyClass:last-child {
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: +1, imo this is the most technically correct answer (compared to mine and others), worth noting however that it would not work on IE8 and under which still represents a rather sizeable audience

Answer (score 2):

The following rules would provide the desired effect. First element will have no margin, but effectively any consecutive element would have `margin-left:5px;`.

```css
.MyClass {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.MyClass + .MyClass {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Well supported across browsers, IE7+

*the `+` adjacent selector matches an element that is a next sibling of another element, in the example above it's a `.MyClass` element following another `.MyClass` element*

Answer (score 0):

selectors as like this one

```css
.MyClass + .MyClass {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

More info http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors